# Share Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

Is it possible to setup a virtual machine on Azure and have that same instance of the virtual machine visible to multiple users?

We are an ISV. Our users are scattered globally. We would like to use an Azure virtual machine to guide users though setup of our software. Ideally our helpdesk would demonstrate our software on the VM while the new user looked on.

The software is ultimately installed on the users local machine. The virtual machine is just for offering support.

We see this as a potential alternative to a product that allows the helpdesk to remote into the user's machine.

Comment: Thank you @David Makogon for fixing the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can just use the users and groups dialog in Windows Server to create multiple users, and then give those users Remote Desktop access. This isn't specific to Azure though, it's just the capability of Windows Server.

See: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732336.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your response @theadriangreen. I know we can give users remote desktop access, but will this allow the users to see the same instance our helpdesk is running so we can guide them through our software, or will it give the user their own instance of the desktop?

Comment: It would be the same virtual machine instance. If you wanted to guide them through then you would have to share screens.

Comment: Thank you again @theadriangreen. Perhaps I framed my question badly. We want the user to see the same screen on the VM as the helpdesk. Are you able to refer me to guidance on how to share screens?

Comment: Screen sharing software such as Skype or Skype for Business will do it. See for example: https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10215/how-do-i-share-my-screen-in-skype-for-windows-desktop

Comment: thanks again @theadriangreen but that doesn't really address the issue I raised in my original post. We are looking for an alternative to the user having to install/configure screen sharing software on their machine. We were hoping to be able to share the screen on a VM by some simple method for the user such as sending them a link.

Comment: No. You will still need screen sharing software.

Answer (score 0):

On the other hand there is a limit for user quantity by default. See

https://serverfault.com/questions/549297/how-to-enable-the-2-concurrent-1-console-sessions-on-windows-server-2012